# How to delete element from nested list with a criterion

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested list, whose sublists have different numbers of levels. This makes my problem different from the other problems on the site.

```
pts={{{{a1, b1, c11}}, {{a2, b1, c21}}, ..., {{an, b1, cn11}, {an, b1, cn12}, {an, b1, cn13}, {an, b1, cn14}}, ..., {{a(m-1), b1, c(m-1)1}}, {{am, b1, cm1}}}, ..., {{{a1, bn, c1n}}, ... ,{{am, bn, cmn}}}}
```

I need to delete the element if the difference between its 3rd number `c` and a reference value `cref` is larger than a threshold.
I hope to obtain a list like

```
Newpts={{{{a1, b1, c11}}, {{a2, b1, c21}}, ..., {{an, b1, cn11}}, ..., {{a(m-1), b1, c(m-1)1}}, {{am, b1, cm1}}}, ..., {{{a1, bn, c1n}}, ... ,{{am, bn, cmn}}}}
```

in which `{an, b1, cn12}, {an, b1, cn13}, {an, b1, cn14}` have been deleted according to `Abs[c-cref]>10^-5` say.

Here is an example

```
pts={{{{0, 1, 1.129}}, {{0.005, 1, 1.129 }}, {{0.01, 1, 0.56471}, {0.01, 
1, 0.56471}, {0.01, 1, 0.56472}, {0.01, 1, 1.129 }}, {{0.015, 1, 
0.56471}, {0.015, 1, 0.56471 }, {0.015, 1, 0.56472}, {0.015, 1, 
1.129}}, {{0.02, 1, 1.129}}, {{0.025, 1, 0.56471}, {0.025, 1, 
0.56472}, {0.025, 1, 0.56472}, {0.025, 1, 1.1285}}, {{0.03, 1, 
0.58219}}}, {{{0, 2, 1.129}}, {{0.005, 2, 1.129 }}}}
```

I want to delete the element whose 3rd element is close to a reference value, say `cref=0.5647189`, the expected result is

```
Newpts={{{{0, 1, 1.129}}, {{0.005, 1, 1.129 }}, {{0.01, 1, 1.129 }}, {{0.015, 1, 1.129}}, {{0.02, 1, 1.129}}, {{0.025, 1, 1.1285}}, {{0.03, 1, 0.58219}}}, {{{0, 2, 1.129}}, {{0.005, 2, 1.129 }}}}
```

I guess it should use `DeleteCases`. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does `pts /. {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ /; c-ct < 10^-5} :> Nothing` work? You could also try the levelspec `{-2}` in `DeleteCases` if the triples are all at the lowest level.  An explicit example, edited into your post, with the desired output will helpful for testing.

Comment: @march I have added an example for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to use the level specification for `DeleteCases`, which will work provided that the ordered triples of numbers are always at the lowest level possible in their list.  Using the explicit example from the OP,

```
DeleteCases[pts, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ} /; Abs[c - cref] < 10^(-5), {-2}]
```

yields a list identical to `Newpts` in the example.  The point is that we want to look at the second-to last level of the list, where the ordered triples will be located.  (The `{-1}` level is the level of the numbers in each of these lists.)

This also works:

```
pts /. {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ /; Abs[c - cref] < 10^(-5)} :> Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor variation of the second answer by @march: Using the `Between` function,

```
cref = 0.5647189;
\[Epsilon] = 10^(-5);

result = pts /. {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, 
    x_?NumericQ /; 
     Between[x, {cref - \[Epsilon], cref + \[Epsilon]}]} ->  Nothing

result == Newpts (*True*)
```